# MQTT retries when Exception in messageArrived method

Tags: java, callback, message-queue, mqtt, mosquitto

I have an MQTT callback that forwards part of the data from the message received via a SOAP endpoint, but when the SOAP endpoint is faulty those messages just get lost and never arrive at the final consumer.

I'm aware of the different QOS and the delivery tokens, but I'm not sure if any of those would actually help me retry sending those messages for example after triggering an exception. Can messages be "returned" to the topic for later retrying or something like that to ensure proper processing of the complete message?

On the client side I'm using Eclipse-Paho, via Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

From this repository:
    https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases

On the server side:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
mosquitto 1.3.4-2 (MQTT version 3.1/3.1.1 compatible)
```

What else should I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once delivered to a client a message is totally gone from the MQTT system.

It is up to you to build any storage and retry logic into the MQTT client app to handle any failures in down stream systems.

Comment: Ok, I get it...any suggestions on such? Resending to the topic perhaps?

Comment: No, that's going to redeliver the message to the client immediately which would just loop if the SOAP end point is down. It all depends on how critical it is you don't lose a message and message delivery rates

Comment: Delivery rates can be quite relaxed, catching up once every 5 mins up to even 60 could be tolerated, but not losing messages.